# What consequences can be after calling an asynchronous method in deconstructer?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I am currently working on a game project that requires some data synchronization with a remote server. This data is just game state like unlocked levels or players items. So I have a singleton object that is responsible to push local data to the server by using asynchronous HTTP post request. I just can't decide when to call this method.

One idea is sending the updated game state just before closing the game. I am working with c++. Well, I know that deconstructers are not for this, but if I can do it in the deconstructer, I can be sure that all the progress is pushed to the server.

However, I can't really guess the possible consequences of calling an asynchronous method in the deconstructer. Can the application stay alive at least the response arrives for every time? Is doing something like that really bad?

Answer (score 0):

> Can the application stay alive at least the response arrives for every time?

No.

> Is doing something like that really bad?

Yes.

At the end of a destructor call, all members are deallocated in the reverse order of allocation. If something attempts to utilize this deallocated memory (i.e. an async function) it would results in an access violation / segfault / undefined behavior depending on your compiler/OS/source.

In order to guarantee a return, you need to turn your asynchronous call into a synchronous one. Usually this can be done using a lock/notify pattern, or a simple thread join if your application is multithreaded.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on how your code is laid out.

There is nothing inherently wrong about calling an async method from a destructor.  If you want to do something on a different thread, and you can be sure that the thread is not going to need any resources from the object being detroyed, go for it.

The issue seems to be that you want to wait for a response, and not close the game until you are positive the save state has been persisted somewhere.  If after you send the async request, the main function is exited, then it is not a good thing.  However, what you could do is ensure that the thread that is doing the async request is joined before you exit.

However, depending on your design, if you were going to do that, you could just have a call before your program terminates that saves the data.  Eg.

```
int main()
{
    Game g;
    //Game loop
    ...

    g.saveState();

    return 0;
}
```